# adding DOM elements through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I am a beginner at using html and CSS. I have a doubt about the display on the UI.
I have a body with html structure as follows:

```
    <div id="wrapper">


        <div id="main">

        <input type="text" id="search"></input> <button id="sub" value="Search"></button>
            <div id="reel">
            <!-- ******************************************************************************************** -->
            <!-- ******************************************************************************************** -->


                <!-- Header Item -->

                    <div id="header" class="item" data-width="400">
                        <h1>test</h1>
                        <p>test</p>
                    </div>

                <!-- Thumb Items -->

                    <article class="item thumb" data-width="282">
                        <h2>You really got me</h2>
                        <a href="images/fulls/01.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </article>



            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

I have used a css to display an image gallery, (presently no image but inside "article" tags). I want to dynamically add articles through jquery, for which I use the following code:

```
$("#reel").append("<article class=\"item thumb\" data-width=\"282\"></article>");
```

This should basically create an empty image in the gallery( I have tired this by adding to the html page). However, nothing can be seen on the UI when I execute the jquery. I can see from firebug the code that the jquery has executed.

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: in JS It's OK to mix single and double quotes so you don't have to escape everything.

Comment: hm - IMHO it creates an empty `<article>` no img.

Comment: as @halfbit said, here you are just appending an empty article, nothing you can see

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `article` to a html node, jquery has a shorthand method for that:

```
var $node = $('<article />');
console.log($node);
[article, constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", jquery: "1.7.1", size: function…]
```

That creates a new node in memory.

then for your function to work you need to change the append to

```
$("#reel").append($("<article class=\"item thumb\" data-width=\"282\"></article>"));
```

cheers!

**EDIT**

As pointed out in comments jquery automatically does that for you, you might be having the node appended, did you inspected with the DOM navigator to check if the node already exists?

In the comments you say that they are missing attributes, try replacing double quotes enclosing the html with single quotes like this :

```
$("#reel").append('<article class="item thumb" data-width="282"></article>');
```

Comment: you can append string too, no need to wrap it inside jQuery object: `content
Type: htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery`

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I tried using this as you sugested: 
var $node = $('<article/>'); 
console.log($node); 
$("#reel").append($("<article class=\"item thumb\" data-width=\"282\"></article>")); 

But I still see nothing on the UI.
Please refer to the snapshots:

Before and after the jquery:
http://grab.by/us6Q

How I want it (adding a empty article in html page)
http://grab.by/us74

Comment: please, use [Chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/logging) for DOM inspection and javascript debugging, do not rely on visuals or supositions

Comment: I see the DOM is added for the article, but some of the attributes differ. I have two questions;
1. if we apply the same class, shouldnt it be exactly the same DOM elements. Is there a way to make exactly the same DOM element?
2. If I set the attributes manually, will it work?